# Converting Curl to Nodejs Axios - Obtaining an Access Token

Tags: node.js, curl, oauth-2.0, axios, access-token

I am currently using curl in order to obtain an access token so I can consume an api with said token. The curl command I use is as follows:

```
curl --user <client_id>:<client_secret> https://api.ed-fi.org/v3/api/oauth/token --data 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

It works and all...**but** instead of curling I want to utilize the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library to get this access token instead.

Here's what I have but it doesn't work.

```
const buff = new Buffer.from('<client_id>:<client_secret>';
const base64data = buff.toString('base64');

axios({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'https://api.ed-fi.org/v3/api/oauth/token', 
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${base64data}`
        },
        data: { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' } 
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `Content-Type` (default for axios is JSON) and pass `body` just like you did in case of `curl`:

```
axios({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'https://api.ed-fi.org/v3/api/oauth/token', 
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${base64data}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```